# What would you call a sliding door that slides up and down and how would you make it's mechanincs?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am working on a package collection system and I was wondering how I could do the mechanics of a door that slides up and down. I have thought of using pulleys with string or linear actuators, but all of those are quite unreliable. I would like to hear your ideas.

Comment: This is one of those cases where it is both better and cheaper to purchase something commercially available. The development cost are spread over many doors and the manufacturer gets better pricing through volume.

Answer (score 1):

I would call such a door a vertically sliding door, as opposed to a laterally or horizontally sliding door.

Regarding the mechanism, weights, pulleys and either cords or chains are used for [sash windows](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sash_window) would work for doors as well. [Sash balances](https://www.mightonproducts.com/products/sash-window-hardware/sash-balances) are a alternative to cords and counter weights.

Answer (score 0):

Take look at garage doors.

There are many tried and tested systems. Some are sectional, some solid.

For example my garage door is 60 years old and is still in perfect condition. I had to change the remote opener a couple of times.

There are industrial heavey service doors mostly made of steel to make them hard to break open.

They have some heavy lifters mostly pulling the door up by chains.

Some of the new commercial service doors have electronic transmitters with layers of codes to be able to set by the manager of the store and automatically change according to daily schedule to deffrenciate admittance to proper employee/s.

Comment: It has to slide up from the bottom.

Comment: @PSONGDALI That's how the typical sliding garage door (at least in north america) works. They tend to slide up and fold over (or in some cases, roll up), but the folding part isn't necessary, of course.